# Configuring subdirectory as root apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, localhost

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu.  On Windows, I was running XAMPP for my local server, on Ubuntu I am running the standard LAMP stack with PHP 7.

My websites are set up as subdirectories within my Apache root folder.  The problem with this is that relative paths / XPATH does not resolve correctly. For example on my Wordpress site, a URL will point to localhost/wp-content instead of localhost/mysite/wp-content.  I would like for the subdirectories to be treated as a root directory.

I have read about several ways to do this with htaccess, but 1) They only worked partially for me 2) I'd rather not have to configure htaccess for every site I am deploying.  I also could set up a number of virtual hosts (this is plan B)

Does anyone know of a way to configure Apache so that it defaults to treating subdirectories as root directories as I would like it to? Or any advice on a better way to do things?